# PHP Regex to get numbers before string with parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, parentheses

Trying to grab the numbers in front of (h), (w) and (d).  These are dynamic and I can't get the syntax for it:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Make: Mymake</li>
      <li>Model: R-22GTF</li>
      <li>Dimensions: 13.25&#34; (h) x 20.13&#34; (w) x 18.5&#34; (d)</li>
      <li>Sold Individually </li>
      <li>Weight: 0 lbs.</li>
    </ul>

if (preg_match("/Dimensions: ((?:\d+)(?:\.\d*)?)/", $desc, $DIMS) == true)
    { echo $DIMS[1];}
```

The above only returns `13.25`.  I would like each in its own array or own variable.  Each as defined by the number before (h), the number before (w), and the number before (d).

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to research regex syntax, as this is not a complex or difficult thing to do. I suggest trying to ***learn*** rather than running to SO to get someone else to do it for you. `(?:` tells PHP that you ***don't*** want to capture the group inside the parentheses.

Comment: Funny I've been looking for an hour what that means and Google couldn't help me explain that.

Comment: *(tip)* http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Please define *each*. Then take care that subpattern matching is limited in PHP, you need to write all patterns for each subgroup you'd like to match.

Comment: I tried googledoesntwork.com but its not up yet =p.  BTW I was looking for "what does colon do in REGEX" none of those sites told me, thanks for googling for me though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = "    
     <ul>
      <li>Make: Mymake</li>
      <li>Model: R-22GTF</li>
      <li>Dimensions: 13.25&#34; (h) x 20.13&#34; (w) x 18.5&#34; (d)</li>
      <li>Sold Individually </li>
      <li>Weight: 0 lbs.</li>
    </ul>";

$re = '/.* (\d+\.\d+).*\(h\) .* (\d+\.\d+).*\(w\) .* (\d+\.\d+).*\(d\)/';
if(preg_match($re, $input, $matches))
   echo sprintf("H: %s   W: %s   D: %s\n", $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
?>
```

Comment: This won't match `" 13.25&#34; (h)x 20.13&#34; (w) x 18.5&#34; (d)"` or `" 13.25&#34; (h)  (w)  (d)"` but OP's are sometimes unaware of the problems with scraping.

Comment: True, but the output looks like something generated by a server, so it seems safe to assume that these variations will not occur. If the server varies the static parts, ie. "(h)x" vs "(h) x", or writes "" instead of "0.00&#34;", then who knows what to expect from that server. And if that really is the case, then I guess OP really has to learn a little regex.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex bellow, hope i understood well what you are trying to extract :)

```
[\d.]+(?=&)
```

EDIT:

global regex

```
/[\d.]+(?=&)/g
```

ALso if you want to test various combinations of regexes, please try some live online regex validators like:

> http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It will match your expressions as you type them.

Comment: From my understanding this is only grabbing the `13.25` again.  I need to try and grab the other numbers as well and throw them into a variable.

Comment: if it doesn't grab all, try it with the global iteration like in my edited post

Comment: Nice link to the regexp-training tool... It's been a while since I played around with regexps :)

Comment: Nice tool.  Although this makes sense and works with the link provided, it is giving me an error still `Unknown modifier 'g'` when I plug in `if (preg_match("/[\d.]+(?=&)/g", $desc, $DIMS) == true)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a print_r($DIMS) on this

`Dimensions:[^\d.;(<]*([\d.]*)[^;(<]*;[^(<]*\(h\)[^\d.;(<]*([\d.]*)[^;(<]*;[^(<]*\(w\) [^\d.;(<]*([\d.]*)[^;(<]*;[^(<]*\(d\)`

expanded

```
Dimensions: 
   [^\d.;(<]* ([\d.]*) [^;(<]* ; [^(<]* \(h\)
   [^\d.;(<]* ([\d.]*) [^;(<]* ; [^(<]* \(w\)
   [^\d.;(<]* ([\d.]*) [^;(<]* ; [^(<]* \(d\)
```

Its a little strict on validation, but its greedy, so redundant overflow restrictions are necessary. You can just replace the negative classes with `.*?` if you want.